# Sorting second array accordingly to the indexs of first sorted array

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

**I have two arrays with same size.**

`ArrayList<ProfileClass> array1= new ArrayList<>()`
`ArrayList<Double> array2= new ArrayList<>()`

array1 = {b,d,a,c}
array2 = {2.0,4.0,1.0,3.0}

Now I need to sort array2 in descending order.
`Collections.sort(array2, Collections.reverseOrder());`
`Expected result: {4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0}`

Therefore, indexes of these values before sorting against each value is not same as it is after sorting. However the index are changed against each value in array2, I want array1 to change indexes against each value accordingly to array2.

`Final Expected result of array1: {d,c,b,a}`

Comment: Are you required to use two lists, can't you use a `Map`?

Comment: Yes, In array1 I am getting data from Firebase then in array2  I do manipulation.

Comment: Isn't it possible to have a class holding data from both arrays ?

Comment: by class you means datamodel class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result by sorting the indexes (0, 1, 2, 3) by the value of `array2` and mapping the result to the value of `array1`.

```
System.out.println("array1=" + array1);
System.out.println("array2=" + array2);
ArrayList<ProfileClass> sortedArray1 = IntStream.range(0, array2.size())
    .boxed()
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparingDouble(i -> array2.get(i))))
    .map(i -> array1.get(i))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
System.out.println("sorted array1=" + sortedArray1);
```

output:

```
array1=[b, d, a, c]
array2=[2.0, 4.0, 1.0, 3.0]
sorted array1=[d, c, b, a]
```

Or you can also do like this.

```
ArrayList<ProfileClass> sortedArray1 = IntStream.range(0, array2.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new Object() {
        double sortKey = array2.get(i);
        ProfileClass value = array1.get(i);
    })
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparingDouble(obj -> obj.sortKey)))
    .map(obj -> obj.value)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Sir I have a question that what if I have a million of record. Will it take noticeable time?

Comment: You should do it and try to time it.

Comment: It takes less than a second to sort a list of 1000000 random doubles on my laptop. `List<Double> a = new Random().doubles(1000000).boxed().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your comment is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a temp Double arrayList. And you should keep the indexes of array2 before sorting.

expected `tmpArrayList = {1, 3, 0, 2}`

then, with these indexes, you can recreate array1.

If you don't have to use array1 as linkedlist, it is better `array1 = new ProfileList[];` for this solution.

Here, i want to say, why is this necessary, you can just put another field to your profileclass object such as `array2Place`?? and update it. I don't get what are you trying to do here actually. Such as, is array2 index of something about array1?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Map using both arrays and get the first array (map value array 1) from the map using the key (Array 2).

```
//Map it
Map<Double, ProfileClass> map = IntStream.range(0, array2.size()).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> array2.get(i), i -> array1.get(i)));
Collections.sort(array2, Collections.reverseOrder());

//Create new array for array1
List<ProfileClass> array11 = new ArrayList<>();
for (Double d : array2) {
    array11.add(map.get(d));
}

System.out.println(array11);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that both arrays (especially the first) can contain duplicates I would suggest the following solution

```java
ProfileClass[] arr1 = new String[] { b,d,a,c };
double[] arr2 = new double[] { 2.0,4.0,1.0,3.0 };

List<Tuple<ProfileClass, Double>> list 
  = IntStream.range(0, arr2.length) // create a stream of all possible indexes
  .mapToObj(i -> new Tuple<ProfileClass, Double>(arr1[i], arr2[i])) // zip the two arrays by the index
  .sorted((a,b) -> Double.compare(a.getItem2(), b.getItem2())) // sort the stream according to the second array
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

// write the result back to the array
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  arr1[i] = list.get(i).getItem1();
  arr2[i] = list.get(i).getItem2();
}
```

here the class `Tuple` is defined as:

```java
public class Tuple<T1, T2> {
  private T1 item1;
  private T2 item2;

  public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
      this.item1 = item1;
      this.item2 = item2;
  }

  public T1 getItem1() { return item1; }
  public T2 getItem2() { return item2; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple to use TreeMap for sorting orders quickly.

```
TreeMap<Double, ProfileClass> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
        map.put(array2.get(i), array1.get(i));
    }
    final Collection< ProfileClass> sortedArray = map.descendingMap().values();
    System.out.println(sortedArray);
```

Comment: Answered you have appreciated is not performance efficient. Streams performs heavy operations behind the program execution. For just 4 elements its takes total 9 ms of time. Just think, If you need to manipulate 100 or 1000 of elements in single array how much time and memory it will process to give you result.

If you want to be programmer, Just think about it and work upon it. You will realise clear difference. Why don't you try easy solution rather than heavy stream operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to have class which holds both values only one sort is required.

In case this is not possible please check the solution from @NiravHR, seems legit.

```java
public class Tester {

    static class Holder implements  Comparable<Holder> {

        private Holder(String letter, Double value){
            this.letter = letter;
            this.value  = value;
        }

        String letter;

        Double value;

        static Holder of(String letter, Double value){
            return new Holder(letter,value);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Holder o) {
            return value.compareTo(o.value);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(this.letter);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

       List<Holder> data = Arrays.asList(
         Holder.of("b",2.0),
         Holder.of("d",4.0),
         Holder.of("a",1.0),
         Holder.of("c",3.0)
       );
       Collections.sort(data, Collections.reverseOrder());


       System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```